# How to use the cut command more then once in a Python subprocess?

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu

I'm trying to use the cut command in a subprocess like this:

```
subprocess.Popen(['cut', '-d', '''(''', '-f2', 'file1.txt', '|', 'cut', '-d', ''')''', '-f1'])
```

and get this error:

```
cut: only one type of list may be specified
```

How can I correct it?

Comment: Using `popen` with an argument list and `shell=False` means there is no shell. Without a shell, you can't have shell pipelines.

Comment: ...you can set up *your own* pipelines with multiple `Popen` objects strung together, which is the way you're supposed to do it; read the module documentation.

Comment: I imagine this can all be done quite easily without the need for subprocess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build the pipeline yourself by combining multiple `Popen` objects:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['cut', '-d(', '-f2', 'file1.txt'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(['cut', '-d)', '-f1'], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()
print p2.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: That is much clearer then my (deleted) attempt. Thanks